# Is there a way to see what's outside main browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have some objects that I need to place outside of the main window then move them with CSS3 transition effect inside the window. I want to be sure if these objects are in their special positions visually. Here is a screenshot of how I think it could look like:

[image: Objects outside of the browser window]

White rectangle represents browser window and the area filled with gray color is the 'outside' area that contains some objects I work with.

Comment: Take a peak around it?

Comment: Outside of the browser window? No way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to see what's outside with Firefox Developer Toolbar.

Right click on any element in Firefox and choose "Inspect Element (Q)"
Than select the 3D-view. It's a small button in the top right corner of the panel.

[image: 3D view button in firefox]

With this, you'll be able to explore the layers of your site, as well as stuff that is not in the normal viewing context.

[image: 3D view in action]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/). This allows yo to set any screen size  you desire. You could set a huge screen size to see if your text is in right position.